# How can I have robot framework test cases in Visual studio-Test Explorer

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, robotframework

I want to link my manual test cases in Azure test plan to robot framework automation test cases( python based test case using selenium library).
Performed below steps :
Created a test project containing my robot framework automated tests.
Checked test project into an Azure DevOps repository.
Created a build pipeline for the project, ensuring that it contains the automated test.

When I executed build pipeline, it appears in Visual Studio - Solution explorer but not in Test Explorer.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlbuA.png)
My question is how can I get robot framework test cases to appear in VS - Test Explorer so that I can associate it to manual test cases in Azure test plan.

Can you please tell me the steps that I need to do in VS to get Test Scenarios.robot in Test Explorer ?

Comment: @ Kevin Lu-MSFT Can you help me with this one if possible

Comment: Hi @Komz, >When you executed build pipeline, it appears in Visual Studio Solution explorer. Could you please update the issue and add a screenshot here? In addition, I can check the build info via team explorer option Builds. By the way, if we run test case in the devops, we cannot get the result in the VS test explorer, I can get the test result when I run it in the VS.

Comment: @Vito Liu-MSFT I have added screenshot. Can you  please tell me the steps I  need to do in VS to get the test cases in Test Explorer

Comment: We can [associate your test case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops#associate-your-test) in the Test Explorer. It seems cannot show the test cases in the Test Explorer. If have any misunderstanding, could you re-describe more details about scenario?

Comment: Is there a solution for the above question? To integrate Azure Test Plan with Robot framework test cases through Visual studio.